# How to construct UDP packet but not send it

Tags: c#, serial-port, udp

This is sort of an odd request.

I have a byte array that I need to send over serial port to another device using C#. However I need to first wrap the byte array within a udp packet, but again, it's going to be sent via serial port, not via udp. Is there a way to construct a udp packet as an array of bytes to then send over the serial port?

I've sent and received messages using udp before but never where the udp packet is constructed but not sent via udp.

Comment: So you just need the IP layer packet, not the Ethernet wrappers?

Comment: @Sam Skuce It would need both the IP and UDP header, not sure if the IP header is the "Ethernet wrapper" or not, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**C# Raw UDP Socket Program Example**](http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/clientserversocketnetworkcommunication8h.html)

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to accept Yochai's answer, as that link (and other pages within that site) provided the code to build both the udp packet and the ip header. For others trying to accomplish it, here is the code:

How to call it:

```
var udpPacketBytes = UDPPacket.Construct(IPAddress.Parse("1.1.1.1"), 1000, IPAddress.Parse("2.2.2.2"), 6100, payloadBytes);
```

UDPPacket class:

```
public static class UDPPacket
    {
        public static byte[] Construct(IPAddress sourceAddress, ushort sourcePort, IPAddress destinationAddress, ushort destinationPort, byte[] payload)
        {
            var bindAddress = IPAddress.Any;

            // Make sure parameters are consistent
            //if ((sourceAddress.AddressFamily != destinationAddress.AddressFamily) || (sourceAddress.AddressFamily != bindAddress.AddressFamily))
            //{
            //    throw new Exception("Source and destination address families don't match!");
            //}

            // Start building the headers
            byte[] builtPacket;
            UdpHeader udpPacket = new UdpHeader();
            ArrayList headerList = new ArrayList();
            //Socket rawSocket = null;
            //SocketOptionLevel socketLevel = SocketOptionLevel.IP;

            // Fill out the UDP header first
            Console.WriteLine("Filling out the UDP header...");
            udpPacket.SourcePort = sourcePort;
            udpPacket.DestinationPort = destinationPort;
            udpPacket.Length = (ushort)(UdpHeader.UdpHeaderLength + payload.Length);
            udpPacket.Checksum = 0;

            if (sourceAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                Ipv4Header ipv4Packet = new Ipv4Header();

                // Build the IPv4 header
                Console.WriteLine("Building the IPv4 header...");
                ipv4Packet.Version = 4;
                ipv4Packet.Protocol = (byte)ProtocolType.Udp;
                ipv4Packet.Ttl = 2;
                ipv4Packet.Offset = 0;
                ipv4Packet.Length = (byte)Ipv4Header.Ipv4HeaderLength;
                ipv4Packet.TotalLength = (ushort)System.Convert.ToUInt16(Ipv4Header.Ipv4HeaderLength + UdpHeader.UdpHeaderLength + payload.Length);
                ipv4Packet.SourceAddress = sourceAddress;
                ipv4Packet.DestinationAddress = destinationAddress;

                // Set the IPv4 header in the UDP header since it is required to calculate the
                //    pseudo header checksum
                Console.WriteLine("Setting the IPv4 header for pseudo header checksum...");
                udpPacket.ipv4PacketHeader = ipv4Packet;

                // Add IPv4 header to list of headers -- headers should be added in th order
                //    they appear in the packet (i.e. IP first then UDP)
                Console.WriteLine("Adding the IPv4 header to the list of header, encapsulating packet...");
                headerList.Add(ipv4Packet);
                //socketLevel = SocketOptionLevel.IP;
            }
            else if (sourceAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
            {
                Ipv6Header ipv6Packet = new Ipv6Header();

                // Build the IPv6 header
                Console.WriteLine("Building the IPv6 header...");
                ipv6Packet.Version = 6;
                ipv6Packet.TrafficClass = 1;
                ipv6Packet.Flow = 2;
                ipv6Packet.HopLimit = 2;
                ipv6Packet.NextHeader = (byte)ProtocolType.Udp;
                ipv6Packet.PayloadLength = (ushort)(UdpHeader.UdpHeaderLength + payload.Length);
                ipv6Packet.SourceAddress = sourceAddress;
                ipv6Packet.DestinationAddress = destinationAddress;

                // Set the IPv6 header in the UDP header since it is required to calculate the
                //    pseudo header checksum
                Console.WriteLine("Setting the IPv6 header for pseudo header checksum...");
                udpPacket.ipv6PacketHeader = ipv6Packet;

                // Add the IPv6 header to the list of headers - headers should be added in the order
                //    they appear in the packet (i.e. IP first then UDP)
                Console.WriteLine("Adding the IPv6 header to the list of header, encapsulating packet...");
                headerList.Add(ipv6Packet);
                //socketLevel = SocketOptionLevel.IPv6;
            }

            // Add the UDP header to list of headers after the IP header has been added
            Console.WriteLine("Adding the UDP header to the list of header, after IP header...");
            headerList.Add(udpPacket);

            // Convert the header classes into the binary on-the-wire representation
            Console.WriteLine("Converting the header classes into the binary...");
            builtPacket = udpPacket.BuildPacket(headerList, payload);

            /*
            // Create the raw socket for this packet
            Console.WriteLine("Creating the raw socket using Socket()...");
            rawSocket = new Socket(sourceAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Udp);

            // Bind the socket to the interface specified
            Console.WriteLine("Binding the socket to the specified interface using Bind()...");
            rawSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(bindAddress, 0));

            // Set the HeaderIncluded option since we include the IP header
            Console.WriteLine("Setting the HeaderIncluded option for IP header...");
            rawSocket.SetSocketOption(socketLevel, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, 1);

            try
            {
                // Send the packet!
                Console.WriteLine("Sending the packet...");
                int rc = rawSocket.SendTo(builtPacket, new IPEndPoint(destinationAddress, destinationPort));
                Console.WriteLine("send {0} bytes to {1}", rc, destinationAddress.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Socket error occurred: {0}", err.Message);
                // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668.aspx
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close the socket
                Console.WriteLine("Closing the socket...");
                rawSocket.Close();
            }
            */

            return builtPacket;
        }
    }
```

Protocol classes: (too long to post here)

[Protocol Class Code](http://pastebin.com/sMegsqvB)

Comment: hello Justin. did this work for you? i tried the code but when i do a wireshark capture on the sender box I see completely different values for all the fields like source and destination port and udp length, etc...

Answer (score 2):

You should construct your UDP packet by perhaps creating a UDP class that contains all data contained in a standard UDP packet.

Data is as [follows](http://mike.passwall.com/networking/udppacket.html):

**Source Port [SP] (16 bits)**: When a connection is attempted, or being conducted, this specifies what port the local machine is waiting to listen for responses from the destination machine.

**Destination Port [DP] (16 bits)**: When a user desires to connect up to a service on a remote machine, the Application Layer program specifies what port initial connections should use. When not as part of an initial connection, this specifies what port number is going to be used for the remote machine as a packet is being sent out to its destination.

**Length [Len] (16 bits)**: This allows for the receiving station to know how many of the incoming bits are supposed to be part of a valid packet. The length is a calculation of how many bytes are part of the UDP packet including bytes in the header. Since UDP always has 4 fields in the header and each has 16 bits, and the data/payload of variable length, we know the length will be 8 + (number of bytes in the payload.)

**UDP Checksum [UDPCS] (16 bits)**:This is a checksum that covers the header and data portion of a UDP packet to allow the receiving host to verify the integrity of an incoming UDP packet. The UDP packet is loaded with a predefined number in the checksum field, and then when the checksum is computed, then the checksum is written over the previous value. When the packet arrives at the destination, the destination machine's OS looks to the 4 header field (bytes made from bits 16 through 31) and pulls them out of the packet, then re-calculates the checksum on the packet without anything in the checksum field. Then the OS compares the checksum calculated with thte one that was transmitted in the packet. If the checksum is the same, the data is fine, and it is allowed to pass on through, but if there is a difference, the UDP packet, and data are dropped, and no attempt is made by the receiving machine to get a new copy, and the sending machine will not try to send that same packet. The packet is lost forever. UDP is not reliable! For a reliable Transport Layer TCP/IP suite protocol see the TCP packet.

**Data (Variable bits)**: As you might expect, this is the payload, or data portion of an UDP packet. The payload may be any number of protocols (often application layer.) Some of the most commonly used UDP protocols include NFS, DNS, as well as mutliple audio and video streaming protocols. If an error occurs in a UDP packet and an error is desired to be fixed, it is left to the application layer to find the error and request its application layer "hunk" or "chunk" of data.

Making a class that holds all this data and fills it up appropriately, overloads `ToString` to allow you to then convert to Byte array.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the reason I don't see any actual packet-level classes in the `UdpClient` in .NET is because frankly it's dead simple because it's a connectionless/stateless protocol.

[The packet format is crazy simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol)

```
bits             0 – 15                   16 – 31
        +-----------------------+-------------------------+
0       | Source Port Number    | Destination Port Number |
        +-----------------------+-------------------------+
32      | Length                | Checksum                |
        +-----------------------+-------------------------+
64      |                                                 |
        |                      Data                       |
        |                                                 |
        +-------------------------------------------------+
```

[Also, do note that the checksum computation does actually have a little bit of complexity to it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Checksum_computation)

Comment: You also have to take endianness into account as well if you're manually crafting the packets.